# Inheriting an alias with child class MRO

Tags: python

```
class parent:
    def fun1(self):
        print("foo")

    fun2 = fun1

class child(parent):
    def fun1(self):
        print("bar")

child().fun2()
```

This code outputs "foo". I'm pretty sure I understand why this is happening, but I'm wondering if there is a straightforward way to implement what I want (inheritable aliases that behave according to MRO, so it outputs "bar") or a reason why this is bad programming practice.

Comment: If you want it to work the other way too, with overrides of `fun2` also overriding `fun1`, things get even messier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to *directly* do what you want.

To understand why, you need to understand the way method lookup works. It's explained in detail in [the Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and I tried to write a less expert-level explanation [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html), so I'll assume you read both of those and just show the effects:

```
>>> child.fun1
<function __main__.child.fun1>
>>> child.fun2
<function __main__.parent.fun1>
>>> child().fun2
<bound method parent.fun1 of <__main__.child object at 0x10b735ba8>>
```

Notice that `child.fun2` is `parent.fun1`, not `child.fun1`. Which explains why `child().fun2` ends up as a bound method around `parent.fun1`, even though the `self` ends up as a `child` instance. Why? Well, obviously `fun2` is not in `child.__dict__` (or we wouldn't need an MRO). And in `parent.__dict__`, it can't be anything but `parent.fun1`.

So, what are the workarounds?

You could make `fun2` into a `property` that forwards to `fun2`, as Patrick Haugh suggested. Or you can just do this:

```
def fun2(self):
    return self.fun1()
```

This solution has the benefit of being dead simple—anyone who can Python will understand why it works.

But Patrick's solution has the advantage of making not just `child().fun2()`, but also `child().fun2` (as an object you can pass around, compare for identity, etc.) work the way you want it to.

---

Meanwhile, there is an idiom closely related to what you're asking for, where a set of public methods that you don't expect to override call a "protected" implementation method that you do. For example, a simple 1D array-math class might do this:

```
def _math(lhs, rhs, op):
    # not actually a useful implementation...
    return [op(x, y) for x, y in zip(lhs, rhs)] 
def __add__(self, other):
    return self._math(other, add)
def __radd__(self, other):
    return self._math(other, add)
# etc.
```

And now there's no asymmetry between `__add__` and `__radd__`, only between the "public" interface (`__add__` and `__radd__`) and the "protected" one (`_math`).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very straightforward way—that's perfectly OK:

```
class Parent:
    def fun1(self):
        print("foo")

    def fun2(self):
        return self.fun1()


class Child(Parent):
    def fun1(self):
        print("bar")


Child().fun2()  # -> bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have `fun2` be a property that returns `self.fun1`

```
class Parent:
    def fun1(self):
        print('foo')
    @property
    def fun2(self):
        return self.fun1

class Child(Parent):
    def fun1(self):
        print('bar')

Child().fun2()
# bar
```